# C Binary conversor but with not integer numbers (float)

Tags: c, binary, integer, converters

I'm doing this decimal to binary conversor, but I don't know how to make it convert not integer numbers, such as `2.5`, `1.567` (float variables).
What can I do?

this is the code, it works for int numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
                    
int main(void) {
    
    int option, a, binary, auxiliarBinary;
    float b;
    
    printf("Type an option to convert: \n");
    
    printf("Type 1: Int\n Type 2: Not int number\n");
    scanf("&d", &option);
    
    if(option==1) {     
        printf("Type an int number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        
        if(a>=0) {
            for(auxiliarBinary=20; auxiliarBinary>=0; auxiliarBinary--) {
                
                binary = a>>auxiliarBinary;
                if(binary&1) {
                    printf("1");
                }
                else {
                    printf("0");
                }
            }
            printf("%d, positive");
        }
        else {
            for(auxiliarBinary=20; auxiliarBinary>=0; auxiliarBinary--) {
                
                binary = a>>auxiliarBinary;
                if(binary&1) {                  
                    printf("1");
                }
                else {
                    printf("0");
                }
            }
            printf("%d, negative");
        }
    }
    else if(option==2) {
```

I tried to make this binary conversor but it's only functional with integer numbers so I'm trying to figure out how to make it work with not integer numbers.

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: There are some answers at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244044/working-out-floating-point-numbers-in-base-2-10-and-16).

Comment: There are many ways to represent a decimal floating-point value in binary. You first need to define the format, only then you can write some code.

Answer (score 0):

The method of converting an integer to a binary string is the same as converting any raw data to a binary string. Some methods:

- Cast the address of any variable into a pointer to character type:

  ```
  unsigned char* ptr = (unsigned char*)&some_variable;
  ```

  This is utilizing a special rule that allows you to iterate across each byte of the variable, from `ptr[0]` up to `ptr[sizeof(some_variable) - 1]`. Apply shifting and bitwise AND masking from there.
- Or convert the `float` etc variable into a suitable integer type using `union` "type punning". For example if you know that `float` is 32 bit on a certain system you could do:

  ```c
  typedef union
  {
    uint32_t u32;
    float f;
  } pun_t;

  pun_t pun_intended = { .f = 3.1415f };
  ```

  And then use `pun_intended.u32` as any integer type, again apply shifting and bitwise AND to mask out binary digits.